# Network driver does not work after Windows update KB4480966

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I have an Asus PCE-AC88 as WLAN adapter on my PC.
My network driver does not work after the emergency Windows 10 update [KB4480966](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4480966/windows-10-update-kb4480966).
It worked initially after the update but after one blue screen of death it finally stopped working after just stopping all 5 to 10 minutes after startup.

Installing the latest drivers for the device did not help in my case.
When looking at the device manager the WLAN device failed with code 10.

Some news coverage on similar issues:
https://mspoweruser.com/microsofts-latest-windows-10-1803-kb4480966-emergency-patch-predictable-causing-major-issues/

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the update KB4480966 via Windows Update.

- Search 'Windows Update settings'
- Select 'View update history'
- Select uninstall updates
- Select the update KB4480966

Restart.

The network drivers did not work for me at this point. I had to reinstall the drivers first.
Uninstall the drivers for the WLAN adapter. In my case this consisted of the following steps:

- Download the drivers for your device.
- Start the installer
- Select uninstall
- Restart

Then install the drivers and restart again.

Comment: Hmm, after another blue screen of death after 30 minutes usage it stopped working again. (Windows Update installed some other updates too apparantly according to the logs but I can't uninstall those.)
I guess I'll wait for some driver update from ASUS or some Windows Update.  

Meanwhile I've switched to a LAN connection to a Fritz WLAN Repeater. I don't want to bother re-installing Windows now.  
Sorry for being no help in the end.